# Cassandra: What does zero default TTL mean?

Tags: database, cassandra, cqlsh, ttl

I have a table that has a zero default TTL and I'd like to know what this means.

I've searched online but I've gotten contradictory statements. None of them explain what a zero DEFAULT TTL means but they explain what setting the TTL to zero would mean. One says you delete the column the other says you delete the columns TTL (which sort of suggests that the row will live forever or it's badly worded). Most sources only talk about non-zero TTLs. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0 TTL means no ttl is set, hence your records will persist forever.